# Shoot me a reminder 20 minutes after logon please

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey, reminder

Is it possible to create a reminder notification to notify 20 minutes after a computer is logged onto by any user account?

The goal is to have the notification be triggered after 20 minutes of usage of the computer after a logon indicating it's being used by someone.

Comment: What do you need a reminder for? And if you need it to be an AutoHotKey script, then add that info to your question

Answer (score 6):

Write a script that waits 20 minutes then shows a message box. Schedule it using the Scheduled Task Wizard, or place it in the "Startup" folder. Note that by doing the latter you will receive a reminder 20 minutes after logging on:

```
WScript.Sleep 1200000
WScript.Echo "That was hard"
```

Write these lines to a file called 'sleep_20m.vbs' and use that script via:

```
Scheduled Task Wizard -> Run at system startup
```

Comment: i need that script

Comment: I have added the script...

Comment: is this auto hot key script?

Comment: No, I have given you a solution to your problem that does not involve autohotkey

Comment: Although I need AHK script but where i need to put this code?

Answer (score 5):

If it doesn't have to be a AHK script, and you are running Vista or Win 7 the Task Scheduler can handle this too.  If you run a simple batch files like:

```
@echo off
echo Reminder message here.
pause
```

Then you can have Window's Task Scheduler run the batch file 20 minutes after login.

[image]

[image]

You need to type in the 20 minutes because the drop down has 15 minutes but you can change that.

[image]

Comment: but i'm using xp

Comment: You should be adding this kind of info to your question, that way people don't give answers you might not be able to use...

Comment: but i already added "Windows-xp" and "autohotkey" as a tag

Comment: @Jitendra - this will apply to XP too, though the dialogs might be slightly different. Plus it does help to add the information to the body of the question as well as the tags - people don't always read everything and it can't hurt to repeat the important points.

Comment: @ChrisF, this will not apply to Windows XP. You cannot delay a task that runs at system startup on Windows XP. See my answer above that works around this.

Answer (score 5):

If it must be an AutoHotkey script for some reason:

```
Sleep, 1200000
MsgBox Here is a reminder
```

You can schedule the script to run with task scheduler as shown in the other answers, or simply drag the script to the startup folder in the start menu. If you have a big script file already which you use extensively, add this to the top of it, and drag the AHK executable to the startup folder in the start menu.

Comment: will try this. and how to add multiple reminder

Comment: Like every 20 minutes? Put `loop {` at the beginning of that code and `}` at the end.

Comment: Why I need autohotkey solution because i can't install any sotware . i can use only portable application in office PC :)

Comment: @Jitendra - If you run a scheduled task as outlined in the other answers you're not installing anything either. Again this sort of information should be in the question.

Comment: @ChrisF - see my tags. AHK was mentioned from start

Comment: @Jitendra - I know it was in the tags from the start - I was pointing out that a) adding the information to body of the question doesn't hurt and can help and b) the fact that you can't install any software should have been mentioned in the question too.

Comment: @ChrisF - Ok I agree with your first point. on 2nd point why i haven't added that i can't install bcoz "Autohotkey" was added as tag and it can be installed portabely

Answer (score 0):

Thinking a little bit out of the box, get a pen drive and add [something like this](http://www.pendriveapps.com/pc-chrono-alarm-clock/) to it:

[image: alarm clock]

If your computer is able to login directly to the user, you just need to add the software to your startup and leave the pen drive plugged in when you turn on.

Just in case, [here's another (paid) option](http://acapsoft.com/det.php?prog=GigAlarm). It looks very good and has a 30 day unlimited trial.